# ¿Cómo actualizar toda una columna e incrementa su valor en un porcentaje?

Tags: laravel

Necesito resolver un problema: Actualmente mi código suma un numero a toda una columna

```
 Personal::where('subcategoria_id', $numerosubcategoria)->increment('precio', 10);
```

a toda la columna precio le suma +10.

Ahora necesito sumarle a la columna **precio** un porcentaje.  Ejemplo: +10%

Ayuda, por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es calcular tú el incremento, cambiando de `increment` a `update` y ejecutando el cálculo. Mi laravel es muy malo, pero debería ser algo como:

```
Personal::where('subcategoria_id', $numerosubcategoria)
    ->update(['precio' => DB:raw("precio + ((precio * 10)/100)")]);
```

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ es LA observación, gracias! Igual, es lo mismo que le comentaste en la pregunta, sólo que no me fijé por ir a mirar documentación pa escribir la respuesta medio bien. :)